# What is a District Militiaman?

Tags: russian-language, andrey-kurkov, death-and-the-penguin

When Viktor had to leave town for a few days, he had no one to watch his penguin, so he called the "district militiaman" and asked him to check on him while he was gone.

What, exactly, was a "district militiaman"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's "участковый" in Russian, a shortened designation of "участковый инспектор милиции" - local police inspector (=district police officer, local policeman). Note that "militia" is a term used in soviet time for "police", and it is still used in some post soviet countries.

From [Russian wikipedia](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8) (translated from Russian):

> The district police officer is an official of the police..carrying out
> official activities aimed at protecting the rights of citizens living
> in the corresponding administrative-territorial area, as well as
> citizens who have suffered from criminal encroachments on the
> specified territory.